# transfer 10 GB data files from cloud server to Sharepoint using putty connection

Tags: sharepoint, putty

I have to transfer 10 GB data to the sharepoint. but before moving to sharepoint I have to connect to the cloud server where I have saved those 10 gb data files...

So my transfer will be using PUTTY , from cloud server to sharepoint.

Is it possible to connect to the cloud server and sharepoint at the same point using PUTTY

Answer (score 0):

Although you can connect to a onpremise sharepoint server via putty, you won't be able to upload files to a document library. The only ways are Http, WebDav, or using some Kind of api (webservices, rest services) with the object model. You also have to take care of the Maximum upload size of sharepoint. You didn't specify if you are using Sharepoint Online or Sharepoint OnPremise nor the Version you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter indicated you cannot directly transfer the data from the cloud server into SharePoint. You will have to "download" the data using putty and then upload the content using http(s), WebDAV or an API.
10 GB is not a lot of data. You may encounter problems with:
 - long URLs (exceeding 260 characters)
 - illegal characters (e.g. #)
 - blocked files (e.g. dll files are blocked on on-premise)
 - maximum file sizes

NB: The uploaded documents will end up with a new modification date.
The easiest way to transfer the files from your local machine into SharePoint is to use explorer view (and break the 10 GB set into smaller chunks). Alternatively use a 3rd party tool (see e.g. https://collab365.directory/office365-sharepoint/best-sharepoint-migration-tools/ or use a SharePoint Add-in) to upload the content. Please note that some tools offer trial versions but they do not upload 100 % of the content.

Paul | SLIM Applications